# spark submit executor memory/failed batch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have 2 questions on spark streaming :

1. I have a spark streaming application running and collection data in `20 seconds` batch intervals, out of `4000 batches` there are  `18  batches` which failed because of exception :

> Could not compute split, block input-0-1464774108087 not found

I assumed the data size is bigger than spark available memory at that point, also the app `StorageLevel` is `MEMORY_ONLY`.

Please advice how to fix this.

2. Also in the command I use below, I use executor memory 20G(total RAM on the data nodes is 140G), does that mean all that memory is reserved in full for this app, and what happens if I have multiple spark streaming applications ?

would I not run out of memory after a few applications ? do I need that much memory at all ?

> /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/bin/spark-submit  --master yarn  --deploy-mode
>   client   --jars  /home/blah.jar   --num-executors 8  --executor-cores
>   5   --executor-memory 20G --driver-memory 12G --driver-cores 8
>   --class com.ccc.nifi.MyProcessor    Nifi-Spark-Streaming-20160524.jar

Answer (score 0):

It seems might be your executor memory will be getting full,try these few optimization techniques like :

1. Instead of using StorageLevel is MEMORY_AND_DISK.
2. Use Kyro serialization which is fast and better than normal java serialization.f yougo for caching with memory and serialization.
3. Check if there are gc,you can find in the tasks being executed.